# How to load dynamic pages with data from a local JSON

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've just started learning Next.js, so thanks for your patience with my question. I'm trying to generate dynamic pages (and routes) from data loaded from a local JSON file (`data.json`). I will not be doing this in production - just trying to learn Next.js.

**partial file structure**

```
|
|- pages
   |- members
     |- [role].js
   |- index.js
|- assets
   |- data.json
```

**data.json**

```
{
  "people": [
    {
      "name": "Amy",
      "role": "administrator"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bob",
      "role": "manager"
    },
  ]
}
```

**Desired result:**
I'd like to be able to navigate to `/members/administrator` and have the page be rendered with the person's name ("Amy").

I've [read this](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props) doc regarding `getStaticProps`, something that I know will be involved.
I've also tried using [this tutorial](https://www.vitamindev.com/next-js/getstaticprops-getstaticpaths-typescript/). In my version of the problem, I am using typescript, but I am just looking for a simple, js/jsx solution for now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data you can use getServerSideProps() like this:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const data =
        await require("/path/data.json");

    return {
        props: {
            data,
        },
    };
}
```

And then get the role assigned with useRouter()

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
```

And get the role from router query:

```
const { role } = router.query;
```

And don't forget to pass the data to your functional component

```
export default function Role({ data })
```